# Python RegEx: жадность с конца строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу разобраться с правильным паттерном для RegEx. Есть файлик с кучей строк следующего вида:

- "Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, gotcha"
- "Lorem, ipsum, go7ch4"
- "Lorem, ipsum, dolor, g0tch4"

Мне нужно написать код, который бы находил во всех строках последнее слово. И я никак не могу сделать так, чтобы мой паттерн перестал быть жадным. Вот мой код:

```
def gotcha_exctractor(line):
    pattern = re.compile(', (.+?)$')
    match = pattern.search(line)
    return match
```

В лучшем случае, когда строка имеет вид `"Lorem, gotcha"`, функция работает нормально, но если сунуть в нее строку длиннее, она выдает слишком много. Например, при `"Lorem, ipsum, gotcha"` я получаю `"ipsum, gotcha"`. Понятно, что под мой паттерн подходит и `", gotcha"`, и `", ipsum, gotcha"`, и что мне нужно куда-то воткнуть таблетку от жадности, но у меня что-то не выходит. Вроде, документация говорит, что для этого нужно сувать `"?"` после спецификаторов `"+"`, `"*"` и `"?"`, но у меня ничего не робит. Как сделать, чтобы это все дело было менее жадным?

Comment: А если `line.split(', ')[-1]`?

Comment: Попробуйте сайт https://regex101.com/. Отточите там свою регексу

Comment: @entithat Это хороший вариант, не подумал о нем, спасибо. Но я все так же не понимаю, почему мой код не работает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Регулярное выражение ищет совпадение в строке слева направо. В выражении `, (.+?)$` первым символом идёт запятая, значит, в `Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, gotcha` будет найдена первая запятая, та, что после `Lorem`. Дальше, после запятой будет найден пробел. Затем `(.+?)` найдёт `i` в `ipsum`, и тут же после этого `$` попробует определить, в конце ли строки находится индекс. Так как это неправда, в дело вступает backtracking:  `(.+?)` захватывает `ip` и снова `$` проверяет, находимся ли мы в конце строки или нет. И так далее, пока `(.+?)` не захватит целую строку.

Вы можете использовать

```
,\s*([^\s,]+)$
,\s*(\w+)$
,\s*(\w+)\s*$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/UKU2zv/1).

Смысл в том, чтобы ограничить `.` так, чтобы он не находил любой символ. `\w+` найдет 1 и более цифр/букв/`_`, `[^\s,]+` найдёт 1 и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов и запятых.

Comment: Могли бы объяснить для чего искать `,\s` перед группой, если в данном случае это устанавливается как ограничение выбора `[^\s,]+$`, даже группу объявлять не нужно, все будет записано в `full match`. UPD: Разобрался вроде, разница в количестве шагов поиска равна ~10 в пользу вашего примера.